# adding header using grep and word count in bash

Tags: bash, grep, wc

Hi everyone I have a lot (200 or so) files that look like this

```
>Sample_NameA
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
>Sample_NameB
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
```

I need to add a header on every file that consist on the number of samples, the number of letters (A,C,G,T) and the number one.

So for example this first file should look like this:

```
2 441 1
>Sample_NameA
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
>Sample_NameB
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
```

I was thinking of using first grep ">" to count the number of samples because every sample name is preceded by that and using the wc to count the number of characters until another >, but I couldn't manage it. In a moment I will upload my script with what I have so far, but if someone has resolved it jet I would really appreciated it.

Thanks id advance.

Comment: upload? your script should be part of your question.

Comment: Why is the 2nd number 441 instead of 756?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This awk can do all this in one command:

```
awk '{if (d) d=d RS $0; else d=$0}
      />/{s++;next}
      s==1 && /[ACGT]/{gsub(/[^ACGT]+/, ""); n+=length($0)}
      END{print s, n, "1" RS d}' file
2 441 1
>Sample_NameA
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
>Sample_NameB
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
ACGTGTCTAGTATGCATGCATAGCTACGACTACGACTAGCATCAGCATCGACTAGCATCGACT
```

Comment: Hi @anubhava: I used it but the second value, the number of ACG and Ts were not the ones that I expected.

Comment: Yes that part isn't clear to me. How should that be calculated? Can you clarify?

Comment: 441 is the count from first sample only. I though you wanted to count total number from all the samples, is that correct assumption?

Comment: After every sample name on the next line, there are a number of As,Cs,Gs and Ts which I need to count. Every sample has the same number of As,Cs,Gs and Ts so there is no need to go threw the whole file for that, just the As,Cs,Gs and Ts of the first sample.

Comment: Yes, 441 is from the first sample, but all sample have the same number of As,Cs,Gs and Ts.

Comment: Is there a way to add the final print to the header of each file?

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out. +1to question for a good interesting problem :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46874/discussion-between-user3049878-and-anubhava)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
DATA="$1" # for readability; give /path/to/data/file as first argument to the script
SAMPLES=$(grep -c '>' "$DATA")
CHARS=$(grep -v '>' "$DATA" | wc -c)
echo "$SAMPLES $CHARS 1"
cat "$DATA"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of a way to do this with just one [grep](/questions/tagged/grep), but certainly doable with a few pipes.

e.g.

```
> grep -E "^>" file 
2
> grep -E -v "^>" file | grep -o "[ACGT]" | wc -l
756
```

Comment: fix: `grep -o "[ACGT]"`

Answer (score 0):

With full credit to @anubhava, here's a method that doesn't keep the entire file in memory:

```
ed file <<END
1i
$(awk '/^>/ {s++; next} s==1 {l+=length()} END {print s,l,1}' file)
.
w
q
END
```